# Methods to reverse engineer black powder

Tags: weapons, chemistry, firearms

In this scenario a kingdom that has not yet invented black powder has been invaded by an enemy that possess cannons and matchlocks. Since  the invaders are few in number the defenders managed to beat them back and steal a large cache of powder. They are extremely concerned that the invaders will return in force and wipe them out. Therefore they want to learn how to make their own black powder and manufacture it before the enemy returns (which they think could be a few years.) Here are some caveats:

- The defenders took no prisoners successfully, so they can’t learn the recipe through coercion or bribery.
- The defenders have no written recipe or manual from the invaders.
- The defenders have a tradition of intellectual curiosity and a pseudo alchemy/primitive chemistry but have not independently stumbled on gunpowder. They are however aware of all three components of gunpowder (but have no idea that those things together flash.)

So is it possible to reverse engineer black powder, and if so what method would be most efficient?

Comment: Whatever procedure you discover from answers must be *contrived* in your story. Consider [Roman Concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_concrete). It took 2,000 years to [figure out the chemistry](https://www.concreteformworkmelbourne.com/modern-concrete-modernization-using-roman-technologies/) and another six [to maybe figure out the recipie](https://aleteia.org/2019/07/16/scientist-believes-shes-found-the-recipe-for-ancient-roman-concrete-used-2000-years-ago/). And that using modern tech. So, your in-story solution will be contrived. IRL reverse engineering chemistry is very difficult.

Comment: Roman Concrete was mostly just difficult to figure out because its so counter intuitive.  The only significant difference between it and other concreates we've been using for hundreds of years was the use of seawater instead of freshwater.  Salt is known to damage concrete made with freshwater; so, adding it intentionally to your mixture is not the kind of thing modern engineers had any good reason to experiment with.

Comment: @JBH: (1) It is not 2000 years, more like 1400 -- last Roman concrete construction was in the 3rd century, and by the 17th I know for sure that concrete was a well-known construction material. (2) Which is perfectly understandable given that chemistry only emerged as a science in the 1700s. (3) The chemistry of Portland cement was figured out within 50 years of figuring out what this chemistry thing was in the first place. (4) They had and used concrete in the 17th century at least, which I know because it was used in the building of the Canal du Midi around 1670.

Comment: @Nosajimiki While that's all true, it's viewed in *hindsight.* Unless aliens tell the OP's people what to look for, the in-story explanation for how the process was reverse engineered will be contrived. None of the processes discussed in answers would in any way be obvious to the practitioners of the time. In fact, most of the processes wouldn't even make sense to them.

Comment: @AlexP That's all interesting.... what's your point? The provided answers so far are cool, but none of them would be an intuitive process to the "scientists" of the OP's time period. Did the Europeans discover gunpowder independently, reverse engineer it, or obtain the formula from the far east? If I recall my history there's a debate between independent discovery and acquisition of the formula - nobody believes they reverse-engineered the formula.

Comment: @AlexP Technically, we never stopped making concreate.  Various forms of concreate date all the way back to the bronze age.  The Roman variety is just a bit of a special  case because it has survived against deterioration under conditions that other kinds of concrete would not have survived.

Comment: @JBH: AFAIK the Europeans discovered gunpowder independently, at least functionally. *Maybe* the original European source got the original formula from somewhere else, but that doesn't matter. For all practical purposes, the development of gunpowder in Europe is independent of any other culture, and went along very different lines: by the early 14th century Europeans (and neighbours, such as the Turks) had effective, operable cannon, and nobody else did. The rest is history.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether they took some prisoners or not, as the people invading and operating cannons are very unlikely to be the ones that produce or know how to produce the powder. Just in case you want to add a prisoner without that solving this problem.

Comment: **Sidenote:** powder is one thing, but it is also very unlikely your kingdom has, out of the blue, enough knowledge of metals to make cannons that will not blow up on first shot.

Comment: @AlexP ihe early 14th century Europeans (and neighbours, such as the Turks) had effective, operable cannon, and nobody else did; however, is that mostly related to technology of manufacturing gunpowder, or rather metallurgy technology?

Comment: @Peteris: It is mostly related to having devious minds and a culture favoring experimentation and rewarding promising applications. There was no major advance in metallurgy in Europe between the fall of the classical world and the late Middle Ages. In fact, in the 13th and 14th centuries India and China had at least as advanced metallurgy as Europe, if not more advanced.

Comment: From the (excellent) answers given, it sounds like there would be substantial gaps in knowledge after investigation, I think that having your kingdom embark on a quest to fill in those gaps by infiltrating the enemy could be the most interesting part of the story. Especially if the spies were atypical, e.g. an alchemist who is adamant they could replicate the process if they could just see it in action.

Comment: @TimM. Noted. I like your idea

Comment: Gunpowder was originally discovered by people just dicking around.  But once a human knows something is possible, they can usually figure it out pretty quickly.  They can look at it, they can smell it, then they can experiment.  Modern example - it took the Soviets not long at all to develop the fission bomb, then the fusion bomb, once they knew it could be done.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Much of chemical analysis in the age of alchemy was done by taste and smell.  Yes, this was very hazardous.

First thing is that anyone with a good sample will notice the sulfurous smell of gunpowder.  The black color (and the way it leaves black dust when it's handled) would suggest charcoal is involved.

As @L.Dutch suggested, the taste of potassium nitrate is quite distinctive (to an alchemist, anyway) -- *sal petre* or "rock salt" was well known in Europe before the secrets of making gunpowder found their way from China to the west; it was used to make nitric acid.

Once those three ingredients are known, it would be a matter of testing known to alchemists (in our timeline) before 1300 CE to get a pretty close idea of the proportions.

Then comes the hard part.  If you just mix the ingredients, even in perfect proportion, the product will just burn (sorry, Captain Kirk, if the diamonds didn't nix your bamboo cannon, the burn rate would).  Instead, one must grind the saltpeter and sulfur into the pore in the charcoal, a process usually done with the "green powder" kept damp -- both to reduce the risk of ignition from friction, and as an aid to getting the saltpeter *inside* the charcoal.  This makes what was called "serpentine" powder (probably because one of the early guns was a serpentine, referring to the shape of the holder for the glowing match).
Once everything has been ground to the point where the ingredients can't be separated, then one must press the powder -- again, done damp, this makes a hard cake which, when thoroughly dried, is broken up and sieved to size the granules.  This is "corning" and produces powder that would serve well through the 19th century -- essentially similar to what's still sold today (except modern powder gets one additional step, tumbling with graphite to coat the granules, making them meter more smoothly and offering slight protection against accidental ignition by static sparks).

In our history, it took more than two centuries for powder (at least in the West) to progress from "fireworks" to gun propellant, and that was after Westerners in the late 13th century had learned from traders what the Chinese put in their powder (which, by then, the Chinese were using in war rockets and small bombs, perhaps even primitive guns).

Comment: That's "corned" gunpowder. It is of course much better than "serpentine" gunpowder made by grinding the components together dry, but it was a later development. By the time that corned gunpowder was developed, everybody who was not an illiterate barbarian already knew what gunpowder was. The question is set in the fleeting time period when some people knew about gunpowder and some didn't.

Comment: @AlexP Or, as I read it, when the less advanced folk know *about* it, from it being used against them, but lack the knowledge to make it.  BTW, thanks for the reminder about "serpentine" vs. "corned" -- I've thought about making my own, and remember the process to get essentially modern powder, and forgot it was used for a century or more without corning.

Comment: I wonder whether that grinding process could be reverse engineered too. I don't know if this is true but you might be able to see by looking at the powder that it doesn't contain any separate grains of saltpeter or sulphur, and therefore conclude that the ingredients must be more thoroughly combined somehow. (This would be easier if you have some kind of magnifying glass, which I guess you might or might not do given the historical period.)

Comment: @N.Virgo Magnifiers were known in Roman times, but clear optical glass was very hard to come by (I've read that one of the Ceasars had an emerald cut/ground to a concave lens to correct nearsightedness).

Comment: You might want to check out the (re)invention of gunpowder in Hoban's _Riddley Walker_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddley_Walker

Comment: @N.Virgo: Corrective eyeglasses were known and used in Europe at least since the mid-1200s. I would say that if they could make eyeglasses they could surely make magnifying glasses. (In real history, magnifying glasses were already known in the classical world; in the Antiquity, the usual form was a glass globe filled with water. Handheld magnifying glasses became available in the 11th century.)

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Fortunately, optical glass is not needed for making a magnifying glass. Plain ordinary glass is perfectly adequate. If you go to your favorite big box retailer you will find in the stationery and writing implements section quite a few cheap and cheerful Chinese magnifying glasses made of ordinary acrylic plastic, or, at best, ordinary glass...

Comment: Fair enough, my side point about magnifying glasses wasn't thought through. I googled "invention of the magnifying glass" and got "mid-1200s" as the answer, but that must refer to a modern hand-held optical glass - it should have been obvious to me that you could magnify stuff before that. A small bead of glass will work as a basic microscope, and it should be possible to make that as soon as you have glass.

Comment: @N.Virgo Actually, van Leeuwenhooke's first microscope used a drop of water (later mixed or replace with glycerin to reduce evaporation) for a lens.  No glass required.  That wasn't invented until the 17th century, though, and compound microscopes are effectively very short-range telescopes, requiring knowledge from about the same time.  Viking farseeing crystals (one-piece telescopes of 2-4x magnification) date from the 8th century or so, however.

Comment: @AlexP clear window glass was barely ahead of optical glass, though, in terms of invention time, and the ability to make it intentionally in the form of a lens (other than spherical) came along with eyeglass making.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Which is why for a couple of centuries eyeglasses fell as a natural monopoly to the island of Murano in Venice. Window glass is hard to make not because clear glass is hard to make (it is not), but because *flat* glass is hard to make in large sizes. Windows which did not distort the view became cheap only in the 20th century, after the invention of the [Fourcault process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourcault_process).

Comment: Yes, although grinding lenses in cast iron molds didn't and doesn't require the glass start out flat.  Bullseye glass or cylinder blown sheet works fine.

Answer (score 16):

Burning it will produce an obvious odor of sulfur dioxide, showing it likely contains sulfur. Tasting it will show it contains some types of salts, likely immediately identifying saltpetre as at least a major component. This probably won't be a surprise, the substance was known from ancient times.

First, wash in pure water. Filter the solution and crystallize the soluble components. Taste, color, shape of the crystals, their solubility, their weight, their behavior when put in a flame...it'll be pretty straightforward to verify what you have as high-purity potassium nitrate, or saltpetre.

Then, the presence of some sulfur in the remainder will be easily identifiable by smell, and the appearance strongly hints of charcoal. Sulfur can easily be distilled off and recrystallized from vapor.

This leaves a black powder strongly resembling charcoal. With further heating, it burns without any odor (except maybe some weak sulfur residue), like charcoal would. Maybe it's charcoal?

You now have three probable components and their rough proportions. You can now mix them, and...find that the result doesn't work nearly as well as the black powder you analyzed. You can now waste a lot of time trying to identify the nonexistent missing ingredient (maybe it's coal, or some specific kind of charcoal, or treated somehow?), or work out that what you're missing is the manufacturing process that intimately incorporates the sulfur and saltpetre into the pores of the charcoal. A close examination of the original and noting that it's not just three separate powders mixed together, and is probably a lot coarser than the extracted charcoal, might put you on the right path. A microscope would help, if you have such a thing.

How long this is likely to take depends on how sophisticated the original blackpowder was and how sophisticated you need the reproduction to be. The actual history of black powder development spanned centuries and involved many different approaches of varying effectiveness, and quite a few fires and explosions.

Answer (score 16):

### They don't need to reverse engineer gunpowder at all

The concept of a gun is a far more important thing to discover than any particular propellant.  Gun powder is just one way of firing a bullet using expanding gasses, but you don't need gunpowder.  What you need is a rapidly expanding gas.  To this end, what you are looking for is anything that burns, and a method for making it burn very quickly and any alchemist from any time period probably has access to at least one substance that meets that requirement.

To prove this point, when I was little, my 12 year old brother figured out how to make a gun that could fire a steel ball without gun powder.  He read a book about how medieval cannons worked, and then within a few days of using what resources he had at his disposal, he designed his own powderless gun.

In his case, he solved the problem with alcohol. While alcohol does not explode like gunpowder, he's already observed that it creates a fireball when you first light it from the vapors in the air; so, he fashioned a simple hand pump attached to a screen to aggravate the alcohol inside a sealed tube to fill the tube with as much vapor as possible, then ignite it.  Basically he got around the need for a rapidly self-oxidizing reaction by using a thermobaric explosion as the propellant.  The result was a small gun that could crack plywood using a 1/2" metal ball.  With a bit more refinement, the technique could be scaled up to a weapon of significant military value (at least compared to other early firearms).

And this is just one alternate solution.  Maybe your alchemists can't figure out any explosives; so, your blacksmiths figure out how to make a compressed air gun instead.  Or maybe they use honey or coco powder instead of charcoal which have both been used in certain historical gunpowder recipes. Maybe they come up with a working design for a [steam cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_cannon). Heck maybe their knowledge of chemistry is good enough they can skip straight to figuring one of the variations of cordite having just not had a good reason to want to make something like that yet.

My point being that if a 12 year old boy can figure out how to make a gun within days of learning how they work, then somewhere in your kingdom is an inventor who can look at a guns mechanical features and figure out how to make some sort of analog with or without an exact black powder recipe.

Comment: I like it. This comes up in time travel stories a lot too. Or alien visitation stories. If every top scientist in the world got a good look at a clearly levitating UFO emitting no noise, then simply knowing that such a thing is scientifically feasible will set off a wide range of experimentation to figure out "how". Financing "anti-gravity device research" is probably hard to come by today (because it's not "how", it's "if") but if it was shown to absolutely be possible it would spur major research immediately.

Comment: Great answer. Farmers deal with this today ([grain dust explosions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OetGMX9Lus)). Under the right conditions, there are a lot of things that can create a satisfactory boom.

Comment: The problem is that most "things that go boom" aren't suitable for guns.  You need a [low explosive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive#Low), one where the reaction moves slower than the speed of sound in the explosive.  Most explosives are high explosives, where the reaction moves faster than the speed of sound, generating a shockwave that is highly effective at shattering gun barrels.

Comment: That’s a super cool story with your brother

Comment: The limitation here is that gunpowder (as well as other explosives) contains oxidizer in its mix. Alcohol (and most other things that burn) does not. Creating an explosive mix (ex. alcohol + air) is either an accident or an engineering challenge of a level that exceeds the level of gunpowder making. It's relatively easy to create a "proof of concept", but very challenging to create a cannon which has practical value.

Comment: The ‘compressed air gun’ comment is a bit offhand in this answer, but should not be taken lightly. Air guns are actually a lot older than many people think (the oldest still in existence dates from 1580, and is actually on exhibit in the Swedish Royal Armory in Stockholm), and it is absolutely possible to make relatively easily usable ones (at least as easy as early firearms) that can drop a human target with decent aim. They also require less robust engineering in many cases than conventional firearms, and can be much easier to maintain as well.

Comment: @JamieB: Examples at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74093/short-story-involving-a-toy-saucer-with-fake-antigravity and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74090/scientists-shown-a-fake-anti-gravity-device-to-motivate-them-to-build-the-real-t for stories involving trying to leverage that trope.

Comment: @Mark When talking low explosives there are actually many possible low explosives, but very few are used commercially.  The thing there are not a lot of options for is the oxidizer.  Saltpeter is the only low explosive oxidizer available to a low tech civilization,  but the fuel can be all sorts of stuff (charcoal, sugar, honey, oil, lard, alcohol, zinc powder, etc), a stabilizer like sulfur  may or may not be necessary based on your fuel and ignition method, and even the oxidizer may be optional in making a low explosive if you do like my brother did and mix the fuel well enough with air.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn, most historic compressed-air guns have the downside that they take longer to re-load than a gunpowder musket; multi-shot ones tend to be "bursty" (you get twenty shots, then need to spend half an hour pumping the air pressure back up).

Comment: @Mark  Most early gunpowder civilizations only equipped thier men with 12-30 shots; so, a 20-shot weapon was actually normal for a soldier's entire ammo supply.  However, these air guns could unload thier entire ammo supply in the time the enemy took to get off thier first 2-3 shots.  So, they really were the superior weapons.  The only reason they never saw mainstream use was that they were too hard and expensive to make en masse.  From the late medieval period up until the 1940s "military grade" weapons were normally whatever the cheapest, not the best, options were at your disposal.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, air guns are only superior if you can win the battle in the first few minutes.  After that, your soldiers are stuck using bayonets against an enemy who still has ammunition.

Comment: @Mark Again, 20 shots was very average for a musketeer to carry.  If you are so outnumbered to the point that there are still enemies left after everyone's fired 20 shots, then you already have a huge problem.  At least this way you now have the option to charge or retreat while the enemy still have a lot of shots unfired.  But if you had to spend 10-20 minutes firing those 20 shots with gunpowder weapons, you'd have been shot back at 20 times before having to decide what to do when the ammo runs out.  Not 2-3 times.

Comment: But if both sides are of near equal size and using the battle line tactics of the day, then you would in fact win the battle in those first few minutes.

Comment: @Nosajimiki, very few battles are won by killing all the enemies.  Most are won by breaking the enemy's will to fight.  The first time you face someone with your fancy 20-shot air rifles, you're probably going to win because the sheer shock of that volume of fire will cause them to break and run.  The second time?  They'll know that if they can stand the first five minutes, you'll be easy pickings.

Comment: "if they can stand the first five minutes" <- You don't stand getting shot 20 times in an open battlefield.  Basically, this would have the same effect as the invention of the gas operated repeater, it would quickly force combatants to entrench instead of forming battlelines.  But once you are looking at trench warfare, the reload time is not a huge impediment since nearly the entire battle is fought in the minute or so it takes to cross no mans land before it devolves into a melee anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Black powder is made by mixing potassium nitrate, charcoal and sulfur.

First step would be to try treating the powder with water: charcoal and sulfur would not be dissolved, potassium nitrate would. The solution water could then be tested to assess the nature of the salt. A possible testing would be by taste, as it is odorless with a sharp, cool, salty taste.

To separate coal from sulfur, sour gas could be used, as sulfur it is well soluble in it. Sour gas is natural gas or any other gas containing significant amounts of hydrogen sulfide. Alternatively, other organic solvents might be employed.

Once the ingredients are known, it would be a matter of experimenting with the relative ratios until finding the right one.

Comment: It may be useful to explain that black power is a mixture, not a chemical compound. In the early days it was a *coarse* mixture. The components can easily be identified under a modest magnifying glass -- at least the yellow sulfur and black coal are unmistakable. Blowing gently over the powder will tend to separate the components.

Comment: I wonder if the potassium nitrate would crystallize when you let the dissolved gunpowder dry out.

Comment: @AlexP I know gunpowder is a mixture, I’m just asking how someone who’s never been taught about it would figure out it’s components.

Comment: @NixonCranium: You look at it closely, maybe with a magnifying glass. You notice that it is made up of something black which looks suspiciously like coal dust, something yellow which looks suspiciously like sulphur, and some mysterious white dust. You separate the components, maybe by dissolving the white dust in water (the coal and suphur don't dissolve) and crystallizing it by evaporation. You taste the white crystals, and identify saltpeter. (Remember that all three components were very well known ever since the Antiquity. The new piece of knowledge is what they do when ground and mixed.)

Answer (score 3):

## Have a skilled alchemist look over it with a magnifying glass and taste it.

It's a mixture of a few common substances, not some fancy chemical compound. Just have a professional look at it. They should be able to see the distinctive components and get extra information by smelling and tasting them. Sulfur is very distinctive in appearance and taste and smell, so is coal, potassium nitrate is a bit harder since it's a white powder, but the salty sharp taste can be distinguished with experience.